# How to merge k sorted arrays in to one array with this method? - Solved

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, merge, mergesort

```
ArrayWithLength merge_k(ArrayWithLength *arrs, size_t count) {
    ArrayWithLength ret;
    ArrayWithLength temp;
    ArrayWithLength temp2;
    int len_array = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        temp = arrs[i];
        len_array += temp.len;
    }
    
    ret.arr = (uint16_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint16_t) * len_array);
    ret.len = len_array;

    if (count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrs[0].len; i++) {
            ret.arr[i] = arrs[0].arr[i];
        }
        ret.len = arrs[0].len;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        temp2 = combine(ret, arrs[i]);
        free(ret.arr);
        ret = temp2;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I really don't understand why the code wouldn't work. I've tried many ways to solve this problem but I think that is the best solution I can provide with my current knowledge.

The concept is pretty easy. Combine just merges ret with the next array in arrs and stores the new array in temp2, after that it's stored in ret again.

I would really appreciate any help and I will thank you in advance!

P.S.: This is my first question on stack overflow, so please excuse if anything is missing or weirdly explained from myself.

```
Arrays (count = 5):
  [8, 8, 2]
  [9, 8, 4, 1]
  []
  [8, 8, 2]
  [8]
===  Expected: [9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 2, 2, 1]
===  Recieved:  [9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 2, 1, 2, 8]
```

This is one of the tests which failed. I assumed the problem is in combine(arr1, arr2) but It gets all the tests right but in any case here is also combine:

```
ArrayWithLength combine(ArrayWithLength arr1, ArrayWithLength arr2) {
    ArrayWithLength ret;
    uint8_t len_arr = arr1.len + arr2.len;
    ret.arr = (uint16_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint16_t) * len_arr);

    if ((arr1.arr == NULL || arr1.len == 0) && arr2.arr != NULL) {
        ret.len = arr2.len;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.len; i++) {
            ret.arr[i] = arr2.arr[i];
        }
    } else if ((arr2.arr == NULL || arr2.len == 0) && arr1.arr != NULL) {
        ret.len = arr1.len;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.len; i++) {
            ret.arr[i] = arr1.arr[i];
        }
    } else if ((arr2.arr != NULL && arr2.len != 0) && (arr1.arr != NULL && arr1.len != 0)) {
        ret.len = len_arr;
        int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0;

        while (i < arr1.len && j < arr2.len) {
            if (arr1.arr[j] > arr2.arr[i]) {
                ret.arr[n++] = arr1.arr[j++];
            } else {
                ret.arr[n++] = arr2.arr[i++];
            }
        }

        while (j < arr1.len) {
            ret.arr[n++] = arr1.arr[j++];
        }

        while (i < arr2.len) {
            ret.arr[n++] = arr2.arr[i++];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `while (i < arr1.len && j < arr2.len) { if (arr1.arr[j] > arr2.arr[i]) {` You are mixing up your `i`s and `j`s. I've shown two neighboring lines of your code - the first one treats `i` as an index into `arr1` but the second one uses it as an index into `arr2`. Decide which is which, and keep them straight.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped fixing my code. I appreciate that a lot!